Let $G$ be a group and let $a$ be an element of $G$ with finite order $n$. Then for any integer $i$, the $|a^i|$ is $n/gcd(i,n)$.
I need help with the following proof.
Statement: Let $G$ be a group and let $a$ be an element of $G$ with
finite order $n$. Then for any integer $i$, the $|a^i|$ is $n/gcd(i,n)$.
Proof: Suppose that for some positive integer $j$ we have $(a^i)^j = e$. Thus $ij = nk$ for some $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Letting $d = gcd(i,n)$ we have $j(i/d) = k(n/d)$. Now $gcd(n/d,i/d) = 1$ thus $n/d$ divides $j$. How can I now infer that $|a^i| \geq n/d$?
What I tried: I know that $n/d$ divding $j$ implies that $n/d \leq j$ and if $j \leq |a^i|$, I would be done. However, I don't think that is the case.

$\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ring

I don't know what that means?

You can choose $j$ to be any positive integer with the property $(a^i)^j = e$. In particular for $j := |a^i|$ you get $n/d \leq j$, as you said.

Informally but intuitively, $ij=nk\iff j=n/\frac{i}{k}$. Now, the denominator in the RHS, say $d$, is a divisor of $n$ (because $j$ must be an integer), which is also a divisor of $i$ (because $i=kd$). Therefore $j=|a^i|$ iff $j$ is the least with such a property, iff $d=\gcd(n,i)$,
